# ColorBlodDetector specify to detect red color for Android

Tags: android, opencv

I am using the ColorBlodDetector Sample of the OpenCV, I would like to modify the code to specify the app to detect red instead of choosing the color by user.

I have modified the code like this in process()

```
mBlobColorHsv = new Scalar(0, 255, 200, 0);
mBlobColorRgba = converScalarHsv2Rgba(mBlobColorHsv);
```

and also modified mLowerBound, mUpperBound and mColorRadius, but the range of red that can be detected is still very small. For example, the app can detect the red of the red ball pen but not the word written by red ball pen and also cannot detect the printed red word.

Please give me some idea how can I increase the color range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the development in Android but for c++, openCV do provide `inRange()` with which you can extract those pixels which lie in that range. I am sure that similar function would be available for Android also. So, instead of trying to extract pixels which have an exact value, you should try to extract the pixel which have values in a range.